# Razor pages - updating label when the input changes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, razor

I want to display a label that shows an item's price, getting that price from the input box(and potentially calculating a new price based on another inputs such as checkbox). I want as soon as the user changes that value in the input, the controller to calculate everything with the new values.
How can I do that?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `keyup` event to achieve this requirement. Below are examples of `mvc` and `razor-pages`.

***Mvc***

**Home controller:**

```
  public IActionResult Test()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Test(int data)
    {
        //you can do your logic here
        data++;
        return new JsonResult(new { result = data });
    }
```

**Test View:**

```
<input id="input" type="number" />
<div id="other"></div>
@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        $("#input").keyup(function () {
            var data = $("#input").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/home/test",
                data: { "data": data },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    $('#other').html(response.result);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

***Razor pages***

In your **startup**,add

```
 services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.HeaderName = "XSRF-TOKEN");
```

**PageModel**:

```
 public class TestModel : PageModel
{
    public void OnGet()
    {
    }
    public IActionResult OnPostInput(int data)
    {
        data++;
        return new JsonResult (new { result=data});
    }
}
```

**Page**

```
<input id="input" type="number" />
<div id="other"></div>
@section Scripts
{ 
<script>
    $("#input").keyup(function () {
        var data = $("#input").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "?handler=input",
            data: { "data": data },
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                    $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
            },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                $('#other').html(response.result);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
}
```

Test result:

[image]